# Roleplaying into a rogue archetype: Arcane Trickster

Tags: dnd-5e, new-players, roleplaying, rogue, archetype

I just started playing D&D 5e and I am at that point where I need to choose an archetype for my level 3 rogue. But, I feel that just becoming an arcane trickster make no sense. Why would my rogue suddenly know magic?

I also read that the arcane trickster does not prepare spells like wizards but just knows them. So from what i understand my caracter should find someone to teach him or mimic someone he sees casting it.

Am I understanding it right?

Comment: Welcome. I'm Voting to close your question as Primarily opinion-based.  Your question is too open-ended without any criteria for users to vote on what would be a good or bad answer. This might be better suited to [a forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) like Enworld rather than the Q and A style of stackexchange.

Comment: There is a strict rules question here ("what are the RAW prereqs for an archtype?"), and providing that answer + a link to the discussion forums answer would be more informative. Roughly, "strictly speaking, the only requirements are [blah], but many tables prefer a stronger RP basis. This answer [link] has some resources where you can talk about how to do find the best approach for your group." I can't give a real answer because I don't know 5e)

Comment: @fectin To the contrary: there's no implicit rules question here because the prereqs are super clear in the text and already clearly understood in the question (i.e., none apart from reaching 3rd level). This is a question 100% about rationalising the fiction.

Comment: I see "Am I understanding it right?" as an implicit rules question, because there's no other "it" to understand. But your point is also reasonable.